# Proving maxima for a combinatorial function

Tags: combinatorics, functions, maxima-minima

I have the following function : 
$$f(k)={n\choose k}(1+e^{-k})^n$$
Here $k$ can vary from $0$ to $n$. I plotted this function for different $n$ on wolfram alpha, like [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20(20!%2F((20-x)!*x!))*(1%2Bexp(-x))%5E20%20for%20x%3D0%20to%2020) (for n=20), an found that this function attains maximum value at $k=0$, but I am not able to prove it formally.

Can somebody give a hint how to prove it formally?

Comment: Domain is integers from 0 to n,  where n is some positive integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint : compute the discrete derivative $$  f(k+1)-f(k)= \frac{n!}{(n-k-1)!k!}\bigg(\frac{(1+e^{-k-1})^n}{k+1} -\frac{(1+e^{-k})^n}{n-k}\bigg) $$
and you can then study the function 
$$ x\mapsto \frac{(1+e^{-x-1})^n}{x+1}-\frac{(1+e^{-x})^n}{n-x}$$
to determine the sign of it (when $x\in[0,n)$).